# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Url encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am deploying an ASP.NET MVC 2 (.NET 4) application to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

I have setup the application pool and the website in IIS. The application is using Forms Authentication.

The application works fine if I go to my login page first (http://mydomain.com/authentication/login). I can login and then use the application just fine.

If I just go to the root of the domain or anywhere besides the login page before logging in it redirects to http://mydomain.com/authentication/login?ReturnUrl=%2fsome%2flocation which causes Firefox to give a "Connection was reset" error and IE to say "Webpage cannot be displayed".

If I manually remove the URL encoding (http://mydomain.com/authentication/login?ReturnUrl=/some/location) everything works fine.

So my problem seems to be that ASP.NET (or maybe IIS) cannot process the encoded URL.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Justin

**UPDATE**

I've created an MVC 3 application and copied the files into it. Still has the same problem. Everything works fine when running with Cassini in VS2010.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok so I have simplified this even further. I created a virtual directory off of Default Website in IIS and put in an index.html file that says Hello World. If I go to http://somedomain.com/test/index.html all is fine but if I go to http://somedomain.com/test/index.html?redirect=%2f I get the same "Connection has been reset" error. I guess this narrows it to an IIS problem. Any ideas?

**SOLVED**

It turns out there is nothing wrong with my application or IIS. It is actually a problem with my workstation. Attempting to view any URL that has an encoded forward slash in it (%2F) causes this error in all browsers. Viewing the application from other computers works fine.

Comment: Is the application pool running in integrated mode?

Comment: Yes the application pool is in integrated mode.